# CSS :after elements overlapped

Tags: css

HTML

```
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
```

CSS

```
.star {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.star:before,
.star:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.star:before {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(22.5deg, 22.5deg);
}

.star:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(22.5deg, 22.5deg);
}
```

I tried this code but it would only show one element in the end. How to prevent element with star class from being overlapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two elements are both overlapping. You need to offset the second element.

You can use `.star:nth-of-type(2)` to target the second element, and `margin-left` to offset it.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.star {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.star:before,
.star:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.star:before {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(22.5deg, 22.5deg);
}

.star:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(22.5deg, 22.5deg);
}

.star:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
```

Comment: If there's more than 3 divs, then how can I prevent it from overlapping?

Comment: Even with just two stars you would have a problem with this because you have no idea whether 30px is enough (or too much) to clear one star as the star's width (and that of the rotated pseudo elements) is defined partly in em units which can be any size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each star some width.

This snippet assumes you want a bit of space between them so it has set the width to 2em which is enough to clear the angled bits and give a bit of extra space.

```css
.star {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
}

.star:before,
.star:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.star:before {
  transform: rotate(0deg) skew(22.5deg, 22.5deg);
}

.star:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(22.5deg, 22.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="star"></div>
<div class="star"></div>
```

If you want the points of adjacent stars touching then do a bit of trigonometry to work out what fraction of an em you need. Let me know if you need help with this.